# Validate time_stamp in input spark dataframe to generate correct output spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, user-defined-functions

I have a spark data frame which contains multiple columns. one out of which is "t_s" column.
I want to generate a new data frame with following conditions:
 a. if value of "t_s" column is empty, or not of correct format then generate current_timestamp.
 b. if value of "t_s" column is not empty and of correct format then use the same value.

I have managed to write following code, but I also want to plug the code to check if "t_s" is of correct fromat or not?

```
def generateTimeStamp(df: DataFrame) = {

import spark.implicits._
var updatedDF = df
updatedDF = df.withColumn("t_s", when(($"t_s").isNull, current_timestamp()).otherwise($"t_s"))
updatedDF
}


val fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
val df = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fmt)

def isCompatible(s: String) = try {
    java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(s, df)
    true
  } catch {
    case e: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException => false
  }
```

I also want to check condition for value of the column "t_s" with isCompatible() function call.

How to do this?

Comment: Why can you use sparksql and cast `t_s` column to required datetime format, that should serve the purpose.

Comment: i suppose if casting fails it returns null value which i do not want as part of resulting data frame. Either I want correct existing value otherwise new generated current_timestamp().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
val fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

val df = Seq(
  "2019-10-21 14:45:23",
  "2019-10-22 14:45:23",
  null,
  "2019-10-41 14:45:23", //invalid day
).toDF("ts")


df.withColumn("ts", to_timestamp($"ts", fmt))
  .withColumn("ts", when($"ts".isNull, date_format(current_timestamp(), fmt)).otherwise($"ts"))
  .show(false)

+-------------------+
|ts                 |
+-------------------+
|2019-10-21 14:45:23|
|2019-10-22 14:45:23|
|2019-08-20 13:54:23|
|2019-08-20 13:54:23|
+-------------------+
```